# WKWebView takeSnapshot does not work on iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, wkwebview, ios13

I need to take a screenshot of `WKWebView` while app in Background.

But on `iOS13` method `takeSnapshotWithConfiguration:completionHandler:` of `WKWebView` does not work. `completionHandler` never fires when an app does a background task.

This works well on `iOS12`. Also, it works on `iOS13` while app in the `foreground`.

**Reproduce:** see demo project to reproduce https://github.com/Jnis/WebView-Snapshot . Also see videos there.

**Expected:**  `takeSnapshotWithConfiguration:completionHandler` call completionHandler with image while app is in background

**Actual result:**

```
[self.wkwebView takeSnapshotWithConfiguration:configuration completionHandler:^(UIImage * _Nullable snapshotImage, NSError * _Nullable error) {
   // this never calls on iOS13 while app in the background. But it works well on iOS12.
}];
```

So, what I'm doing wrong? Or, does anybody know another way how to save a webpage completely by using `WKWebView` while app in the background?
Thank you!

---

**UPDATED: 13.03.2020**

**Solution:** setting WKSnapshotConfiguration’s **afterScreenUpdates** property to **NO**

```
WKSnapshotConfiguration *configuration = [WKSnapshotConfiguration new];
if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
    configuration.afterScreenUpdates = NO;
}
```